# DataGridView restrict user input

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, input, datagridview

Is it possible to restrict user input to `DataGridView` cell by means of `RegEx`? For example set format of cell input to something like this `[0-9]{2}` to forbid user enter something except 2 digits.

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I was not very clear. I'm aware about `CellValidation` event and that I can check entered value after user input. But I wonder if I can prevent wrong user input **before** this event. I mean that user cannot input letters when cell regex is `[0-9]`. Is is possible?

Comment: Its called a "Mask" when you restrict input value like that: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411511/datagridview-mask-values-in-column)

Comment: I think in that case you should use some javascript/jQuery

Comment: @pawlakppp that works poorly in WinForms :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to prevent invalid values as they're typed, you can handle the `EditingControl.KeyPress` event. Sample code below. You have to modify your regular expressions to allow incomplete values, though. And you should still use proper validation, because there are other ways to get data into the grid (such as copy paste).

```
    private string pattern = "^[0-9]{0,2}$";

    private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.EditingControl.KeyPress -= EditingControl_KeyPress;
        dataGridView1.EditingControl.KeyPress += EditingControl_KeyPress;
    }

    private void EditingControl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar))
        {
            Control editingControl = (Control)sender;
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(editingControl.Text + e.KeyChar, pattern))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ginosaji , your code is good but with `editingControl.Text + e.KeyChar` you're assuming that user enters the last char at the end of the control text. What if the user places the char in the middle of the control somewhere?